# Kann eine KI zuverlässig das Genus oder den Plural deutscher Substantive vorhersagen?

Tags: gender, grammatical-number

Hier wird regelmäßig nach dem Genus eines (Lehn-)Wortes oder nach dem Plural eines Substantivs bzw. nach dem Grund dafür oder nach allgemeinen (Faust-)Regeln gefragt. Selbst Laien können einige Regelmäßigkeiten erkennen und beschreiben. Allerdings treffen in vielen Fällen mehrere dieser Regeln zu, deren Ergebnis sich unterscheidet. Eine Hierarchie der Regeln oder eine andere systematische Lösung für solche Konflikte aufzustellen, scheint aber selbst die Germanistik bisher zu überfordern. Daher meine Frage:

Wurde erfolgreich versucht, eine Künstliche Intelligenz auf eines dieser Entscheidungsprobleme zu trainieren und hat das ggf. neue Erkenntnisse für die DAF-Praxis gebracht?

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ein neuronales Netz bzgl. neuer Erkenntnisse weiterhelfen würde - schließlich ist es eine Black Box, bei der die Entscheidungsregeln verborgen bleiben.

Comment: KI (künstliche Intelligenz) und neuronale Netze sind zwei verschiedene Dinge. Neuronale Netze sind Nachbauten von Clustern aus Nervenzellen. Aus einem neuronalen Netz kann man ebensowenig Regeln gewinnen, wie aus dem Sezieren eines Gehirns unter dem Mikroskop. KI ist ein sehr schwammig definiertes Arbeitsgebiet, zu dem unter anderem auch wissensbasierte Systeme gehören. In diesem Fall hat man als Basis einen Satz expliziter Regeln und handelt danach. Auch hier kann man keine neuen Kenntnisse gewinnen, weil die erhofften Kenntnisse bereits explizit vorgegeben werden müssen.

Comment: Hubert hat völlig recht. Die in ein neuronales Netz eingepaukte Abbildung ist auswendiggelernt. Daraus gewinnt man prinzipbedingt überhaupt keine Erkenntnis. Das ist ja genau die Crux mit den neuronalen Netzen.

Comment: Sehr interessante Frage, die aber leider m.A. nach auch ziemlich off-topic ist. Hier geht es eher um den Stand der Technik der KI als um die deutsche Sprache.

Comment: Ich habe _neuronales Netz_ durch das allgemeinere _künstliche Intelligenz_ ersetzt.

Comment: @tofro Es geht mir eher um den Stand der Computerlinguistik in der Germanistik.

Comment: Du musst deine Frage ein bißchen umformulieren. "Vorhersagen eines Genus" ist leider Unsinn. Das hört sich nach Kristallkugel an. Ein Substantiv **hat** einen bestimmten Genus. Punkt. Da gibt es nichts vorherzusagen. Ich kann entweder einen existierenden Text auf Richtigkeit untersuchen (das sollte in 90% der Fälle mit einem Wörterbuch gelingen, die restlichen 10% brauchen eine semantische Analyse, bei der man aber auch schon ziemlich weit ist) oder einen Text aus einer fremden Sprache übersetzen und den richtigen Genus wählen. Dazu muss ich aber den *fremdsprachigen* Text "verstehen"

Comment: @Janka Was ist an der deutschen Sprache *nicht* "auswendiggelernt"?

Comment: Es ist eben nicht reines Kristallkugeln, ob es _der Genus_ oder _das Genus_ heißt.  Muttersprachler entwickeln automatisch ein intuitives Gespür dafür, das manchmal daneben liegt. KIs sollten das auch ohne Wörterbuch ebenfalls lernen können. Durch geschickte Programmierung sollte es doch möglich sein, eine Liste von hierarchischen Regeln zu generieren oder zumindest statistische Qualitäten anzugeben.

Comment: Ich verstehe immer noch nicht, was genau du suchst, bzw. was "Input" und was "Output" ist - Das könnte z.B. das Modell einer Semantik sein und ein korrekter deutscher Satz oder ein fremdsprachlicher Satz, der korrekt ins Deutsche übersetzt wird. Oder (was ich aufgrund von Mehrdeutigkeiten als unmöglich ansehe) ich werfe ein Substantiv ohne weiteren Kontext in einen Algorithmus und bekomme ein Genus zurück.

Comment: @tofro Letzteres, weitgehend. Oder aber Wortliste plus Regeln als Eingabe und die KI ordnet und bewertet die Regeln.

Comment: @tofro: Die Frage war, ob man aus dem Auswendiglernen eines neuronalen Netzes irgendwelche Erkenntnisse für die DAF-Praxis ableiten kann. Nein, das kann man nicht. Der Lernalgorithmus ist vorgegeben. Variieren kann man nur die Lerndaten. Man gewinnt dadurch die Erkenntnis, welche Lerndaten man in genau diesen Lernalgorithmus eingeben muss, um das spätere Ergebnis zu erhalten. Mehr nicht.

Comment: @crissov: Das ist dann passende Vorverarbeitung der Eingabedaten. Damit erreichst du bessere Ergebnisse bei der Interpolation durch das neuronale Netz. Was du nicht bekommst, ist ein verbesserter Regelsatz. Weil gerade der ja durch das neuronale Netz völlig opak einfach nur auswendig gelernt wird.

Comment: Den Genus irgendwie algorithmisch oder anhand von Heuristiken zu ermitteln, scheint mir ein ziemlich nutzloses Unterfangen, wenn man einfach in einer Datenbank nachschlagen kann. Der Muttersprachler macht es schließlich genauso, nur dass sich die Datenbank in seinem Kopf befindet. Bei einem Wort, das er noch nie gehört oder gelesen hat, kann der Muttersprachler auch nur raten.

Comment: Mich irritiert, dass viele Leute Sprachen als etwas ansehen, das über Regeln zu beherrschen sei. Die Regeln, die man a) vielleicht in der Schule lernt und b) die man als Linguist (besonders als strukturalistischer) sich gerne zusammenbastelt, sind Hilfen, um das für eine bewusste Verarbeitung im menschlichen Gehirn zu umfangreiche Material vorzustrukturieren. Am Ende braucht man aber immer den Blick in die Datenbank, nämlich für die Ausnahmen. Worteigenschaften wie das Genus kann man nicht "errechnen". Abgesehen von einigen historischen Entstehungsregeln sind sie vor allem Konvention.

Comment: Das artet jetzt etwas aus, aber natürlich versucht jede ernstzunehmende Wissenschaft ihren Untersuchungsgegenstand so systematisch wir möglich zu beschreiben, sodass damit u.a. Rekonstruktionen und Prognosen möglich sind. Computer können Gesetzmäßigkeiten ganz anders analysieren als Menschen allein, siehe z.B. das Buzzwort _Big Data_.

Comment: Der Computer analysiert Gesetzmäßigkeiten nicht, er findet sie nicht einmal. Er wendet sie bloß an. Und durch ein neuronales Netz bleibt auch dem Programmierer völlig unzugänglich, wie er sie anwendet.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Die Regeln (...) sind Hilfen, um das für eine bewusste Verarbeitung im menschlichen Gehirn zu umfangreiche Material vorzustrukturieren." - das klingt, als hättest du beispielsweise sämtliche konjugierten Formen aller existierenden und auch noch nicht existierenden Verben bereits im Kopf abgespeichert und die Regeln helfen dir nur dabei, die jeweils passende abzurufen. Das halte ich für abwegig. Ich vermute, die Regeln sind eher die Basis, auf der die Formen gebildet werden (bei Sprachen, die du fließend beherrschst, durchaus auch unbewusst), ungeachtet der Fälle, in ...

Comment: ... denen du eine "Ausnahmesituation" erkennst (die übrigens ihrerseits auch wieder eine Regel sein kann, wie bei Gruppen von starken, analog konjugierten Verben).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the stand of KI and not about the usage of the German language.

Comment: Ist das für eine Hausarbeit? ;) Wie dem auch sei, müssen wir erst definieren was "zuverlässslig" heißt. 96% genauigkeit? 96,1231%?  Man muss sich ja im Klaren sein, dass solche KI-Methoden statistisch verankert sind und von daher **probabilistisch** sind.

Answer (score 2):

Regeln gibt es einige, und die könnte man sicher auch einem Computer beibringen:

- Fremdwörter auf "-or" sind grundsätzlich maskulin
- Fremdwörter auf "-us" sind maskulin (außer "Genus selbst"...)
- Wörter auf "-in" sind (meistens) feminin
- Fremdwörter aus dem Französischen mit "-au[x]" (oder verdeutscht "-o") sind Neutren
- Wörter auf "-er" sind meist maskulin
- Wörter auf "-se" sind feminin
- Wörter auf "-chen" sind meist Neutren
- Wörter auf "-lein" genauso
- Wörter auf "-ung" sind größtenteils feminin
- Wörter auf "-keit" ebenfalls
- ... und viele mehr

Und leider gibt es zu jeder dieser Regeln auch Ausnahmen, die ein Algorithmus kennen müsste. Und es gibt auch viele deutsche Wörter, die sich nur im Genus unterscheiden (der/die/das Band, das/der Bund,...) und dabei vollkommen unterschiedliche Begriffe bezeichnen.

Diese Ausnahmen, und vor allem die letzte, sorgen dafür, dass man die Regeln eigentlich gleich wieder vergessen kann - Man könnte mit einer gewissen Wahrscheinlichkeit, aber nicht Sicherheit, ein Genus bestimmen. *Das kann selbst ein "native speaker" in solchen Fällen nur mit Kontext.* Ohne Kontext ist eine solche Bestimmung alles andere als "zuverlässig".

Baut man ein Stück Software, das eine komplette semantische Analyse eines Satzes ausführen kann (und da ist man dran oder kann es schon), dann hat man die Möglichkeit, den Satz tatsächlich zu "verstehen" und daraus u.U. auch genug Kontext abzuleiten, dass man Genus und Numerus genau bestimmen könnte. Aber wie gesagt: Nicht ohne Kontext.

Comment: "Ausnahmen, die ein Algorithmus kennen müsste" Mir ging es ja gerade um Systeme ohne festen Algorithmus bzw. um die Bewertung, Verbesserung oder Entwicklung von Algorithmen, die auch Menschen anwenden können.

Comment: Crissov hat nicht nach Regeln gefragt, die man einem Computer beibringen könnte, sondern genau umgekehrt: Er hat danach gefragt, was ein Computer, der sich mit deutscher Sprache beschäftigt, uns Menschen beibringen könnte.

Comment: Auch z.B. ein neuronales Netz muss eine Ausnahme "lernen". Dann ist deine Frage weitab von allem, was mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat - Du willst wissen, ob es ein technisches System gibt, dass Regeln aus einem offensichtlich total chaotischen System mit extrem vielen Einflüssen von außen, einer mehrtausendjährigen Geschichte und massenhaft Mehrdeutigkeiten ableiten kann und diese aus den Daten formulieren könnte - Das halte ich für sehr unwahrscheinlich. Eher lernt ein Computer das Singen.

Comment: Mir fällt auf Anhieb kein Substantiv auf "-ung" ein, welches kein substantiviertes Verb darstellt. Ähnlich verhält es sich mit "-lein" und "-chen" (Diminutive) und "-keit". Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob bei einem Fremdwort, welches eine derartige Endung hat aber nicht den passenden "Grund" dafür (also z.B. "-ung", obwohl es sich nicht um ein Substantiviertes Verb handelt) wirklich diese Regeln angewandt würden.

Comment: @MartinRosenau *Zeitung*? Oder doch lieber *Kuhdung*?

Comment: Stimmt: "Zeitung"; die wäre aber weiblich. An "Dung" (männlich) habe ich selbst gedacht, allerdings war ich mir nicht sicher, ob sich "Dung" von "düngen" ableitet (was dann auch eine Art substantiviertes Verb wäre - und trotzdem männlich) oder umgekehrt.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Tut mir leid, mir ist der Zusammenhang zur Frage vollkommen unklar

Comment: Ich habe das Ganze ja auch als Kommentar zu deiner Antwort und nicht als Kommentar zur Frage geschrieben. Eine der von dir genannten Regeln lautet: "Wörter auf -ung: weiblich". Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Regel wirklich "Wörter auf -ung" oder ob sie "Substantivierte Verben auf -ung" heißen muss. Entsprechend stellt sich die Frage, ob das fiktive Fremdwort "Chauhundung" wirklich mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit weiblich wäre. (Dasselbe entsprechend für "-chen", "-lein" und "-keit".)

Comment: Was ist für dich der Unterschied zwischen einem *Wort* und einem *substantivierten Verb* - und wie paßt "Zeitung" da rein? Wenn du die Spezifikation der Regel enger machst, bekommst du nur noch mehr unerwünschte Ausnahmen.

Comment: Ich habe nicht geschrieben, dass substantivierte Verben keine Wörter sind, sondern dass die Regel mit dem "-ung" sich meines Erachtens nur auf substantivierte Verben bezieht. Ich habe mal nach Wörtern gesucht, die auf "-ung" enden und keine Substantivierung darstellen: Wenn es bei Zeitung und Dung bleibt, sind nur 50% dieser Wörter weiblich; zwei Wörter sind auch zu wenig, um eine "Regel" aufstellen zu können. (Nebenbei gibt es mit Sprung und Schwung auch noch männliche Substantivierungen.)

Comment: @MartinRosenau Wenn ich wüsste, worauf du hinaus willst, könnte ich möglicherweise einfacher mit dir diskutieren ;) Die Regeln in meiner Antwort erheben keinen Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit oder gar Richtigkeit - Ich versuche nur zu sagen, das solche Regeln vielzuvele Ausnahmen haben, um als Grundlage dienen zu können. Deshalb sagt man ja auch jedem Deutschlerner: "Das musst du auswendiglernen.". Ich glaube im Übrigen auch, das solche Regeln in jedem Kopf untereinander unterschiedlich priorisiert und mit unterschiedlichen Ausnahmelisten versehen sind, je nach Spracherfahrung.

Comment: "Wörter auf "-er" sind meist maskulin" - ja, wie die Mutter, Schwester, Tochter, Butter, das Futter, Gatter, ... - das sind zu viele Ausnahmen, um noch von Ausnahmen zu sprechen.

Answer (score 0):

Zitat aus "[Link](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2007/09/24/geschlecht-von-fremdwortern/)":

> Gerade bei neueren Lehnwörtern ..., sodass das Wort mit ***mehr als nur einem Genus*** verwendet wird.
>   ... Ob eine der Tendenzen letzlich "gewinnt" und welche das ist, bestimmt der Sprachgebrauch.

Beispiele:

- die E-Mail, das E-Mail
- der Grappa, die Grappa
- der Benchmark, die Benchmark
- der Weblog, das Weblog
- (oder, aus einer Frage auf dieser Webseite:) der Socket, das Socket

Aus dem zweiten Satz des zitierten Abschnitts folgt, dass diejenigen Muttersprachler, die ein neues Fremdwort benutzen, quasi darüber bestimmen, welches Genus denn "richtig" ist und dass das "richtige" Genus erst nach längerem Gebrauch des Wortes in der deutschen Sprache feststeht.

Eine Software, die das "richtige" Genus eines beliebigen, der Software unbekannten Fremdwortes bestimmen kann, müsste folglich vorhersehen können, für welches Genus sich die Muttersprachler in Zukunft entscheiden werden, da man die Software ja nach einem Fremdwort befragen könnte, das im Deutschen noch neu ist, und das zur Zeit noch mit unterschiedlichen Genera verwendet wird.

So etwas ist wohl nicht möglich.

---

Nachtrag (zur Frage von "Gerhard"):

> Warum ist das nicht möglich?

Nehmen wir als Beispiel ganz einfach das Wort "E-Mail":

*Die* erste E-Mail, die Deutschland erreicht hat, ging an die Universität Karlsruhe. *Das* erste E-Mail, das Österreich erreicht hat, ging an jemand anderen.

Damals hat die Pressestelle der Universität Karlsruhe wahrscheinlich eine Meldung herausgebracht, dass "*die* erste Email" in Deutschland angekommen ist.

Irgendwer hat damals unbewusst die Entscheidung getroffen, in irgendeine Pressemeldung "*die E-Mail*" und nicht "*das E-Mail*" hineinzuschreiben.

Möglicherweise ein Journalist, möglicherweise ein Mitarbeiter der Pressestelle oder ein Informatik-Professor oder gar ein Student, der mit dem Mitarbeiter der Pressestelle geredet hat.

Die Pressemeldung wird herausgegeben und sämtliche Zeitungen, Fernseh- und Radiosender halten sich daran. Später halten sich auch alle anderen Deutschen daran, da der Tagesschau-Sprecher ja "*die*" E-Mail und nicht "*der*" E-Mail gesagt hat und es so auch in der "Beispielstädter Rundschau" geschrieben wurde.

Die Tatsache, dass man in Österreich "*das* E-Mail" und nicht "*die* E-Mail" sagt, zeigt eindeutig, dass der Herausgeber der Pressemeldung sich auch anders hätte entscheiden können.

Schlussfolgerung:

Solange man nicht vorhersagen kann, **wer** später einmal ein noch unbekanntes Fremdwort erstmalig "veröffentlicht" (z.B. in einer Pressemeldung, in einem Werbespot, in einem Musikstück ... verwendet), kann man auch nicht vorhersagen, welches Genus dieses Fremdwort einmal haben wird.

Schließlich hängt es von dieser Person entscheidend ab, welches Genus dieses Wort einmal bekommen wird.

Ob diese Vorhersage durch einen Menschen oder durch einen Algorithmus getroffen werden soll, spielt dabei keine Rolle.

Comment: Warum ist das nicht möglich?

Comment: @Gerhard Habe meine Antwort etwas erweitert

Comment: Die Vorstellung, dass ein einzelner Journalist über die Verwendung entscheidet, ist nett aber realitätsfern. Wenn sich 70% der Leute so, und 30% so entscheiden würden, dann wird sich eine solche Aufteilung auch bei Journalisten finden, sofern sie repräsentativ sind. Und wieso soll eine KI das nicht lernen können? Journalisten und IT-Nerds wissen viel, außer dass sie nichts wissen, und so erliegen sie reihenweise und vorhersehbar der Illusion, Fremdwörter aus dem Englischen seien meist sächlich (the e-mail --- it) und das sei relevant. https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/deklination/genus.php

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe meine Antwort noch einmal überarbeitet. Aber nach wie vor würde in meinem Beispiel eine einzige Person darüber entschieden haben, welches Genus das Wort "E-Mail" hat. Und nach wie vor behaupte ich, dass es nicht möglich ist, das Genus eines noch unbekannten Fremdwortes mit Sicherheit vorherzusagen, ohne zu wissen, welche eine einzige Person beim entsprechenden Fremdwort über das Genus bestimmen wird.

Comment: Sicherheit ist doch gar nicht nötig - es ist doch nur nötig, deutlich besser als der User prognostizieren zu können, welches Genus das Wort bekommt. Ich nutze etwa das LanguageTool, um meine Zeichensetzung zu verbessern. Ab und zu setze ich mich über dessen Vorschläge hinweg, wenn ich meine es besser zu wissen. Wahrscheinlich wäre meine Fehlerquote schon besser, wenn ich den Vorschlägen blind immer folgte - durch meine Vetomöglichkeit wird sie noch besser.

Comment: @userunknown In der Frage des Fragestellers ging es aber um eine "zuverlässige Vorhersage". Und "zuverlässig" bedeutet nun mal, dass die Fehlerquote dieser Software irgendwo im einstelligen Prozentbereich liegen sollte. Vor dem Hintergrund, dass fast alle Fremdwörter zunächst einmal mit unterschiedlichen Genera verwendet werden (z.B. "der Task" und "die Task") und sich erst später ein Genus herausbildet, halte ich für ein Fremdwort, das noch gar nicht in Verwendung ist, bereits 70% Treffergenauigkeit für illusorisch.

Comment: Eben, "zuverlässig" ist nicht "mit Sicherheit" - freut mich, dass Du mir da so weit entgegenkommst. Wenn sich kein richtig/falsch ausbildet, wie bei E-Mail oder Blog, dann, so kann man argumentieren, wäre es auch nicht falsch, wenn die KI das andere vorschlägt. Außerdem könnte die KI ja darstellen, dass es wohl mehrere Alternativen gibt. Es kann zudem nicht darum gehen, wie man es in der Zukunft (nächstes Jahr) schreiben wird, sondern es geht immer darum, wie es heute geschrieben wird.